# delete file using button in jsp and ask for another file upload

Tags: java, jsp

When i am using above Code it after refreshing the image was deleting by default.
my target is to after Clicking Delete button it should Delete and ask for another file upload of that particular passportImage
Here is my Code

```
String fileName = "D:\\WEBSITE_FILES\\docs\\OTR\\" + db_unicid + "\\passportImage.jpg";

java.io.File f = new java.io.File(fileName);
if (f.exists()) {
    f.delete();
    out.println("File found");
} else {
    out.println("File Not Found!");
}

String pathimage = "D:\\WEBSITE_FILES\\docs\\OTR\\" + db_unicid + "\\passportImage.jpg";
File fileimage = new File(pathimage);
boolean existsimage = fileimage.exists();
if (!existsimage) {
    out.println("<input type='file' name='passportImage' id='passportImage'  onblur='valFileExt(this.id);' size='50' ><td><input type='submit' value='Upload '/>File not Available");

} else {
    // It returns true if File or directory exists
    out.println("<a href='/WEBSITE_FILES/Incois_docs/OTR/" + db_unicid + "/passportImage.jpg' target='blank'> View Image</a></td> td><input type='submit' id='btnSubmit' name='btnSubmit' value='delete'/></td>");
}
```

Comment: I assume this is all in your .jsp file? You should really have this functionality in a servlet and invoke it from jsp so it does not run everytime you refresh your page.

Comment: i already created a servlet The file also deleting but deleting when i refreshing page..my aim is to delete when i click the Delete Button

Comment: Please post the relavent jsp file and the servlet code.